# Where are the local variables on the saved Example?

Tags: javascript, postman

I create requests with environment and local variables in the URL, and after saving it as an example, I can't find the local variables on the "pre-request script" tab, which is missing.

I'm using postman to define some template requests for my company, and wish to create examples off of those templates.

I created a template which uses the following layout:

```
https://{{url}}/API/{{method}}/{{id}}
```

After a successful request, I tried saving it as an example, which imported the output, params and much more into it.

While {{url}} and {{method}} are environment variables and can be found at the eye icon, the {{id}} is an local variable and cannot be seem after saved as an example.

Upon saving the example, the "pre-request script" tab disappears, so the local variable {{id}} is irretrievable.

Is there anyway to find the {{id}} value (and any other code at 'pre-request script' at that) after it is saved as example?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I needed but use path variables.

While Query Params are automatically detected by Postman, it only catches the GET path, leaving anything else uncaught.

Path variables are very useful, they work the same, but must be declared as follows:

```
https://{{url}}/API/{{method}}/:id
```

It should be displayed at the UI just below Query Params